# Few options in nvidia-settings and stuck on CPUX for Xs on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, nvidia-prime

after 3 days I've finally installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell notebook with a skylake CPU.

Now, I've two main problems:
1) Ubuntu doesn't shutdown, when I press the shutdown button Ubuntu say's: "CPUX stuck for Ys" where X is the number of logical core and Y is the time. I've tried to edit the grub and add various options as: acpi=force or acpi=off and others, but nothing, sometimes the system shutdown and sometimes the system doesn't shutdown...

2) Usually after the install of Nvidia binary properties driver I type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

After this, usually when I type nvidia-settings on terminal, I can switch between the integrated and the dedicated GPU, but not this time!
When I start nvidia-settings there are only 2 options:
-Application Profiles
-nvidia-settings Configuration
and I can't switch between the two GPU.

I have a Dell 7559 with a UHD touch display and my configuration is: Intel i7-6700HQ Skylake 3,5Ghz ,16GB RAM DDR3L 1.600MHz, 128GB Samsung SSD + 1TB HDD, Nvidia gforce GTX 960m GDDR5 4GB.

I have already follow all the guide in this forum but nothing!
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with the Dell 7559 and fixed it by using kernel 4.8.3. It also fixed the soft lock that was happening on suspend. To install a new kernel go to the [index of kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and find the latest one that doesn't have an rc next to it. There are three files that you need:

- The “generic” header file for your architecture (in my case, 64-bit or “amd64”)
- The header file in the middle that has “all” towards the end of the filename
- The “generic” kernel file for your architecture (again, I would pick “amd64” but if you use 32-bit you’ll need “i686”)

You put these files into their own folder. Now open up the Terminal, use the

cd
command to go to your newly-created folder, such as

cd /home/user/Downloads/Kernel
and then run:

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: Since websites outside the Stack Exchange network might change or go offline at any time, answers should include the steps required to solve the problem, and only refer to the external site as a source. Could you please extend your answer to make sure the information will remain available for future readers? ;)